# Is Hadoop designed for solving problems that need multiple parallel computations of the same data but with different parameters?

Tags: hadoop

From the little I have read, I understood that Hadoop is great for the following class of problems - having one massive question answered by distributing the computation between potentially many nodes.

Was Hadoop designed to solve problems that involve multiple calculations, on the same dataset, but each with different parameters? for example, simulating different scenarios based on the same master dataset, but with different parameters (e.g. testing a data mining model on the same data set, but spawning multiple iterations of the simulation, each with a different set of parameters and finding the best model)

E.g. for a model predicting weather, that have a set of rules with different weights, does Hadoop support running the same model, but each "node" running with a different weight values on a learning set and comparingthe prediction results to find the best model?

Or is this something that Hadoop was simply not designed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really something it was designed to do. Typically you would want to be able to distribute different parts of the dataset to different nodes. This is one of the main ideas behind hadoop: split a huge dataset over multiple nodes and bring the computation to the data. However, it still can definitely be accomplished without jumping through too many hoops.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with the MapReduce paradigm, but you could think of the parameters of your models as the "input" to your map task. Put the dataset in some location in HDFS, and write a MapReduce job such that the map tasks read in the dataset from HDFS, then evaluate the model using the given parameters. All map outputs get sent to one reducer, which simply outputs the parameters that gave the highest score. If you make the number of input files (model parameters) equal to the number of nodes, you should get one map task per node, which is what you want.